# Roblox: Editting/Removing Cards from Trello

Tags: api, http, proxy, trello, roblox

I have recently been trying to use [ROBLOX's HttpService](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Sending_HTTP_requests) to delete and or edit for say the description of a Card on a Trello Board.

Though what I've heard is, that these methods require Push/Delete async. Or something of that matter, while ROBLOX only supports Post and Get.

How can i send Push/Delete requests from ROBLOX? 
I was thinking on using a a own server as proxy, but i am stuck at how to implement it.

Comment: I don't recommend using Trello as a database. You can get free cPanel servers easily with unlimited storage with MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

As ROBLOX does not allow methods other than POST and GET, you will indeed need another server to act as a proxy.

I can think of two different solutions, you can either make an API on your server that does all needed stuff, or you can simply use it as a pure proxy.

To make an API would be better (as you can enforce correctness in the requests and hide tokens and sensitive data better), but can be harder to implement.

To make a simple proxy that simply pass on the requests could be solved with [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) and [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
<?php
    $method = isset($_POST["method"]) ? $_POST["method"] : "GET";

    if( !isset($_POST["url"]) )
        die("Requires URL!");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.trello.com/1/" . $_POST["url"] );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Important to note is that an user agent is required when sending requests to trello.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

And that the code is killing SSL (a bad idea, but required if your server can't use it)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Remove those two lines if possible

To use the code from ROBLOX, send a POST request with the "`method`" parameter to the type of method you want to use `POST`,`GET`,`PUT`,`DELETE`,`PUSH` and the "`url`" parameter to the url in the trello API (excluding "http://api.trello.com/1/")

There are [lots of guides on how to set up a PHP on a server](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20set%20up%20a%20PHP%20server), depending on what server you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Trello API](https://www.roblox.com/library/214265621/Trello-API-Original) read through it and it should help you